# Azure function integrating with Private endpoint gives error

Tags: azure-functions, azure-bicep, azure-private-link

I am trying to deploy azure function app and integrate it with private endpoint using Bicep template. The deployment is successful, however the function app link gives the below error.

**Your connection isn't private.**

I have included the DNS profile. In Virtual network I have also added the service endpoint(storage account) and integrated with the function app subnet.

Kindly assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

- I have deployed a function app with v-net integration using Bicep template by following below steps
- Open Visual Studio Code and New Folder and create a file in that folder and use the below Bicep template and save the File

Thanks `@mcollier` for Bicep template

```json
@description('Location for all resources except Application Insights.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('The language worker runtime to load in the function app.')
@allowed([
  'node'
  'dotnet'
  'java'
])
param runtime string = 'node'

@description('Storage Account type')
@allowed([
  'Standard_LRS'
  'Standard_GRS'
  'Standard_RAGRS'
])
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'

var resourceBaseName = uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)
var vnetAddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/16'
var subnetAddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
var subnetName = 'default'
var functionWorkerRuntime = runtime

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-05-01' = {
  name: 'vnet-${resourceBaseName}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: subnetAddressPrefix
          delegations: [
            {
              name: 'delegation'
              properties: {
                serviceName: 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  resource integrationSubnet 'subnets' existing = {
    name: subnetName
  }
}

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-05-01' = {
  name: 'st${resourceBaseName}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }
}

resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2022-10-01' = {
  name: 'log-${resourceBaseName}'
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'PerGB2018'
    }
  }
}
resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: 'ai-${resourceBaseName}'
  location: location
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.id
  }
}

resource serverFarm 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'asp-${resourceBaseName}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'EP1'
    tier: 'ElasticPremium'
  }
  kind: 'elastic'
  properties: {
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: 20
  }
}

resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'func-${resourceBaseName}'
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: serverFarm.id
    httpsOnly: true
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: virtualNetwork::integrationSubnet.id // Specify a virtual network subnet resource ID to enable regional virtual network integration.
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: 'InstrumentationKey=${appInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey}'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix= ${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccount.name};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value};'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~3'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: functionWorkerRuntime
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~12'
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  resource config 'config' = {
    name: 'web'
    properties: {
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
    }
  }
}
```

- After Saving the file follow below steps to deploy Bicep file to azure port as below Right click on `main.bicep` file and click on **deploy Bicep file** as below

[image]

- Select the **deployment name** as below

[image]

- Select the **Subscription ID** to which you want to deploy as below

[image]

- Select the **resource group** as below

[image]

- Select **Parameter File** as **None** (Because the Bicep does not contains a parameter file) as below

[image]

- Select the parameter location same as resource Group location as below

[image]

- Select Runtime as **Node** as below

[image]

- Select **storageAccountType** to **standard_LRS** as below

[image]

- Select **No** After this steps Bicep template will be deployed to the azure portal

[image]

- After a successful deployment Goto azure portal and open the Resource Group you will find as below

[image]

- Open function app and Goto Networking we will see the v-net integration is enabled  as below

[image]

- Then Goto **overview** in function app click on URL you will get as below

[image]

Comment: I think the above bicep doesn't have private end point integration for both azure function and storage account, I need azure function and storage account to be integrated behind private end point.

Comment: Please go through the [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet) it might help